# Change scrollDirection on a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a `collectionView` that scrolls vertically.  Inside the cells of that `collectionView` is another `collectionView` that I have a custom layout for. The layout is currently a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and I want the scroll direction to be horizontal. I have tried a variety of ways to set the `scrollDirection` to horizontal but none of them are working. How do I set scroll direction on a subclass of `FlowLayout`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617720-scrolldirection

Comment: Isn't working. That's the first thing I tried...

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by "isn't working". Setting a flow layout's scroll direction to horizontal does in fact make its scroll direction horizontal. And the fact that it's a subclass doesn't of itself change anything about that.

Comment: Are you setting it too late ? On a completely different note, I feel it is an overkill to have a collection view inside a cell. You could use a `UIStackView` instead

Comment: It "wasn't working" for me either. I forgot to adjust the frame height.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change scroll direction by this code:

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
}
```